# Is it possible to use X-Macro with std::variant (or with template in general)?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, x-macros

I hope to do the following using X-macro with c++17, but since template parameter does not support trailing comma, it does not work for the std::variant part. Is there someway around it?

```cpp
#define LIST_OF_TYPES(X) \
  X(Type1)               \
  X(Type2)               \
  X(Type3)

#define MAKE_TYPE(name) class name {};
LIST_OF_TYPES(MAKE_TYPE)
#undef MAKE_TYPE

std::variant<
#define MAKE_VARIANT(name) name,
LIST_OF_TYPES(MAKE_VARIANT)
#undef MAKE_VARIANT
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a workaround:

```
#define EMPTY(...)
#define IDENTITY(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define IDENTITY2(...) __VA_ARGS__

std::variant<
#define MAKE_VARIANT(name) (,) name IDENTITY
IDENTITY2(EMPTY LIST_OF_TYPES(MAKE_VARIANT) () )
#undef MAKE_VARIANT
>
```

Without `IDENTITY2(...)` this expands to `EMPTY(,) Type1 IDENTITY(,) Type2 IDENTITY(,) Type3 IDENTITY()`. `IDENTITY2` forces it to expand again, this time to `Type1, Type2, Type3`.

---

Or, with [my own macro looping library](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/macro_sequence_for):

<kbd>[run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:16,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:16,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Chttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/HolyBlackCat/macro_sequence_for/master/include/macro_sequence_for.h%3E%0A%0A%23define+LIST_OF_TYPES+(Type1)(Type2)(Type3)%0A%0A%23define+DECLARE_CLASSES(seq)+SF_FOR_EACH(DECLARE_CLASSES_BODY,+SF_NULL,+SF_NULL,,+seq)%0A%23define+DECLARE_CLASSES_BODY(n,+d,+x)+class+x+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0A%23define+MAKE_VARIANT(seq)+std::variant%3CSF_FOR_EACH(MAKE_VARIANT_BODY,+USE_COMMA,+SF_NULL,+EMPTY,+seq)%3E%0A%23define+MAKE_VARIANT_BODY(n,+d,+x)+d()+x%0A%23define+EMPTY(...)%0A%23define+COMMA(...)+,%0A%23define+USE_COMMA(n,+d,+x)+COMMA%0A%0ADECLARE_CLASSES(LIST_OF_TYPES)+//+class+Type1+%7B%7D%3B+class+Type2+%7B%7D%3B+class+Type3+%7B%7D%3B%0AMAKE_VARIANT(LIST_OF_TYPES)+//+std::variant%3CType1,+Type2,+Type3%3E%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.08030221760739,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1500,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors+-E+-o+-%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+15.0.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:27.056698129939512,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x64+msvc+v19.latest%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+15.0.0+(Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50.91969778239262,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)</kbd>

```
#include <macro_sequence_for.h>

#define LIST_OF_TYPES (Type1)(Type2)(Type3)

#define DECLARE_CLASSES(seq) SF_FOR_EACH(DECLARE_CLASSES_BODY, SF_NULL, SF_NULL,, seq)
#define DECLARE_CLASSES_BODY(n, d, x) class x {};

#define MAKE_VARIANT(seq) std::variant<SF_FOR_EACH(MAKE_VARIANT_BODY, USE_COMMA, SF_NULL, EMPTY, seq)>
#define MAKE_VARIANT_BODY(n, d, x) d() x
#define EMPTY(...)
#define COMMA(...) ,
#define USE_COMMA(n, d, x) COMMA

DECLARE_CLASSES(LIST_OF_TYPES) // class Type1 {}; class Type2 {}; class Type3 {};
MAKE_VARIANT(LIST_OF_TYPES) // std::variant<Type1, Type2, Type3>
```

Slightly more verbose, but more readable in my taste.

Here, `#define MAKE_VARIANT_BODY(n, d, x) d() x` is called for each element, with `x` being the element, and `d` initially set to `EMPTY` (4th argument of `SF_FOR_EACH()`). After the first (and any subsequent) iteration, `d` is reassigned to `USE_COMMA(...)` (aka `COMMA`), so starting from the second iteration `d()` expands to `,` instead of  .

Answer (score 1):

Put the comma at the beginning and add a first element of some kind, whether it is relevant or not. One possibility:

```
template<template<typename...> class Tmpl, typename... Ts>
using specialization = Tmpl<Ts...>;

using my_variant = specialization<std::variant
    #define MAKE_VARIANT(name) ,name
    LIST_OF_TYPES(MAKE_VARIANT)
    #undef MAKE_VARIANT
>;
```